# How to pass values to a referenced project?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have two projects  Project1 and Project2, i added Project2 in the references of Project1, now i need to send the Project1 variable values to Project2, how can i achieve that.

Comment: Project 2 has to expose methods/objects that take those parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects don't have values to pass to each other.

If you have a class *c1* in project 1 and a class *c2* in project 2, and you want to pass a value (member property or field or local variable) from a *method* in *c1* 
to a *method* in *c2*, then you can do the following:

```
public class c1 {
    public void m1() {
        int someValue = 1;
        c2 ic2 = new c2();
        c2.m2(someValue);
    }
}

// In project 2
public class c2 {
    public void m2(int passedValue) {
        // do something with the value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. That would create a circular dependency, which you can't do.

---

What you *can* do is have common functionality that both projects need in some project (let's call it Project3), and Project1 and Project2 have references to Project3.

Comment: The question is unclear, but if OP is looking to just pass variables values to Project 2, then this wouldn't be a circular dependency.   It would be a circular dependency if project 1 referenced project 2 and then project 2 tried to reference project 1.  Depends on what OP's actual intent is.

Comment: if i want to use Project1 variables in Project2 then i need to add Project1 to the references of Project2 then it will be a circular dependency, so i cannot use the values of Project1 now.

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Can you clarify on what you're actually doing?

Comment: i have a project written by someone it has a functionality to load two windows forms side by side, now when i click a button in form1 of project1 then form1 of project2 is loaded side to it, project2's form1 has save button now i need some values of project1's form like 'address to save value' in form1 of project2, problem is project2 is referenced in project1. I will give a try to your answer and come back to you.

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS: if that's what you want, then don't you think you should have _told_ us about it?

Answer (score -1):

if a -> b

b.form calls a.form

then you could declare public a.eventargs
instanciate them in b and pass them back to the a.form for processing.

Or

you could just expose properties on a.form and set them from b.form